# How do I replicate the "add task" row layout behaviour of the native iOS Reminder App?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, layout, uiscrollview

The "add task" row in the reminder app sticks to the bottom of the UITableView as overlay, if the row is below the visible area, and fixed to the last row if the row is within the visible area.

Screenshots of the Reminder App:

- [add row attached to last row of the tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQBIw.png)
- [add row overlays tableview at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQXwT.png)

I tried several approaches and could not get it to work how I wanted it:

1. Using a parent UIViewController which constraints a newly added view to the bottom with a lessThenEqual constraint and an equal constraint with lower priority to an empty footerView of the UITableView. This worked quite well but does not account for a small UITableView contentInset (overlaying occurs), the new view does not scroll the UITableView, and it overlays the scrollIndicator of the UITableView. I also dislike the newly introduced UIViewController.
2. Using the UITableView footerView and transform its frame when scrolling occurs. The following code was my first attempt, but the frame did not immediately update after `footerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity` and therefore the frame was unusable. Caching the initial frame led to unexpected offsets and other visual glitches.

   ```
   override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      footerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
      let delta = tableView.bounds.maxY - footerView.frame.maxY
      if delta < 0 {
         footerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: delta)
      }
      tableView.bringSubviewToFront(footerView)
   }
   ```

Comment: You might be able to do it using a table view but I’m pretty sure using a UICollectionView would be cleaner look into custom layout or collection view

Comment: Okay, thank you. I have never used a UICollectionView before, but I think that the sectionFootersPinToVisibleBounds of an UICollectionViewFlowLayout is exactly what I need.